# opening NERDTree to point to my file but with full directory tree

Tags: linux, vim, nerdtree

I'm using vim, cscope and NERDTree and I cannot find how to open NERDTree to be pointing to specific file (one that is an active buffer) but to have root directory equal to directory from which I opened Vim.

Is there a way to do so?

Example:

Lets say that I have a file which I'm editing in ./B/C/d.cpp and I opened vim in directory A.

I want A to be NERDTree root, but when I'm toggling NERDTree -> I want B and C directories to be unfolded.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `:NERDTreeFind` will do that.

```
:NERDTreeFind                                                  :NERDTreeFind
    Find the current file in the tree.

    If no tree exists and the current file is under vim's CWD, then init a 
    tree at the CWD and reveal the file. Otherwise init a tree in the current
    file's directory.

    In any case, the current file is revealed and the cursor is placed on it.
```